# Elasticsearch query throwing an error when using range with bool

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am querying elastic search using `status field` and `range` but getting an error:

> "type": "parsing_exception","reason": "[status] query malformed, no
>   start_object after query name"

Query looks as below:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
            "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "requestDate": {
              "gte": "2018-10-01T08:00:00.000Z",
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "requestDate": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you haven't specified the query type - term or match - against status field. So if status is a text datatype, you should perform a match query:

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": []
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match":{            "status": "IN_PROGRESS"
        }},
        {
          "range": {
            "requestDate": {
              "gte": "2018-10-01T08:00:00.000Z",
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "requestDate": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }

}
```